# Как вернуть строчку с конца до элемента '/'

Tags: c#

Как вернуть строчку с конца до элемента '/'

например site.ru/page-1/image-1.jpg вернуть /image-1

Answer (score 3):

А давайте будем думать не в терминах строк, а в терминах объектов, мы ж пишем на объектно-ориентированном языке? Ваш адрес должен быть в любом случае в объекте типа `Uri`.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://site.ru/page-1/image-1.jpg");
string last = uri.Segments.Last(); // image-1.jpg
```

Если нужно ещё и откусить расширение, то

```
string lastWithoutExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(last); // image-1
```

Answer (score 3):

Если на входе у вас именно абсолютный Uri, нужнен именно последний сегмент, и нужно избежать случайных совпадений в query string, то:

```
var url = new Uri("http://site.ru/page-1/image-1.jpg");
Console.WriteLine("/" + url.Segments.Last()); // /image-1.jpg
```

Разница по сравнению с поиском последнего `/` в обработке строк вот такого вида:

```
var url = new Uri("http://site.ru/page-1/image-1.jpg?some=a/b");
Console.WriteLine("/" + url.Segments.Last()); // все еще /image-1.jpg, а не /b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = @"site.ru/page-1/image-1.jpg";
int index = s.LastIndexOf(@"/");
string result = 
  (@"/" + System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(s.Substring(index + 1), "")).Trim('.');
```

Comment: Я считаю, что подход PashaPash и VladD более правильный. Если у вас есть Uri - то и работайте с ним через Uri, а не как со строками или через библиотеку работы с файлами.

Comment: кхм, кхм, *у меня* ничего нет, я отвечаю на вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = "site.ru/page-1/pic.jpg";
string filename = a.Split('/')[2];
```

Comment: тогда уж просто: `return "pic.jpg";`

Comment: @Igor Ваш вариант получается в любом случае вернет конечное имя?

Comment: получается - да :)